# Yii2 Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'could not find driver' when running yii command

Tags: php, yii2

I am running my application local using Laragon and using mysql database and it works fine. However, when I run the command `php yii`, it gives me this error:

```
Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'could not find driver'

in C:\laragon\www\project_name\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php:647

Caused by: Exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

in C:\laragon\www\project_name\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php:721
```

I've looked through other solutions here like checking my `php.ini` file and making sure the extension `pdo_mysql` is enabled. I tried running `phpinfo()` and it says has `pdo_mysql` enabled. I've checked my extensions on Laragon (Menu->PHP->Extensions) and it is enabled as well.

I also run `php -me` and these are my output:

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
gd
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

My `db.php` configuration:

```
<?php

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=xxx',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'tablePrefix' => 'fbz_',
];
```

I've tried everything but I still keep getting the error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like console version of your php is missing `pdo_mysql` extension. It might be because you have multiple installations of php (for example different versions) or because web server uses different `php.ini` file than console version of php.

Comment: How do I rectify this issue?

Comment: Try running `php -i`. There should be lines `Loaded Configuration File` and `Additional .ini files parsed` somewhere at start of output. That should tell you which ini file you need to check.